# Show that $\lim_{x \to a} kx^2 + mx + n = ka^2+ ma +n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that $$\lim_{x \to a}  kx^2 + mx + n = ka^2+ ma +n$$ (Assume the domain is $\mathbb{R}$)

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Suppose

$$\delta = min\{ \frac{1}{|kx + ka +m|}, 1\}$$

Then we have if $$ |x- a| < \delta$$

$$|(kx^2 + mx + n) - (ka^2 + ma + n)| = |k(x-a)(x+a)+m(x-a)| = |(x-a)(k(x+a)+m)|=|(x-a)|*|(k(x+a)+m)| < |k(x+a)+m|*\delta  = \frac{\epsilon}{|kx + ka + n|}*|kx + ka + n| = \epsilon $$

I am having some doubts about this. I chose $\delta$ to be what it is because of how |f(x)  - L| factors and because of how the largest a fraction can be is 1. It seems as though I may need to say more, in particular about whether delta can be chosen the way I have chosen it. I think I am missing something.

Comment: The choice of $\delta$ depends on $x$, so it's not clear what $\delta$ we are choosing. Over what set does $x$ vary to decide what the minimum you've assigned to $\delta$ is? In fact, that minimum might not exist.

Comment: @bjorn93 thank you for answering. I have edited the question to say that the domain for x is the set of real numbers.

Comment: @bjorn93 perhaps I should not that restrict the value of kx + ka + m to any number but 0.

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality we have
$$|k(x^2-a^2)+m(x-a)|\leq|k(x^2-a^2)|+|m(x-a)|=|k|\cdot|x^2-a^2|+|m|\cdot|x-a|$$

This equals the follwing, before we estimate with $\delta$
$$|k|\cdot|x-a|\cdot|x+a|+|m|\cdot|x-a|\lt |k|\delta \cdot|x+a|+|m|\delta$$

Now we use a sneaky trick to be able to estimate with with the triangle equality again
$$|k|\delta \cdot|x+a|+|m|\delta=|k|\delta \cdot|x-a+(a+a)|+|m|\delta\leq|k|\delta \cdot(|x-a|+|a+a|)+|m|\delta$$

Now we can remove all $x$ from the inequality and estimate with $\delta$
$$|k|\delta \cdot(|x-a|+|a+a|)+|m|\delta\lt |k|\delta \cdot(\delta+2|a|)+|m|\delta=|k|\delta^2+(2|ka|+|m|)\delta $$

Can you solve for $|k|\delta^2+(2|ka|+|m|)\delta-\epsilon=0$? This will give you 2 options of $\delta$, one of which will be positive. That will be your $\delta$ independent of $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew something was missing, but I could not see through the fog.

Comment: it appears the crucial principle I was missing was finding $\delta$ independent of x.

Comment: @Zeta10I must say I'm not so familiar with proving limits like this; for me epsilon-delta proofs usually deal with infinity, and other limits deal with calculus rules and shortcuts/theorems you can use. So I'm not even sure if in this case $\delta$ can't depend on $x$, as that's sometimes allowed in continuity proofs (but not uniform continuity). But if you can find a $\delta$ independent of $x$ you know you'll always be okay.

Comment: I think your intuition is correct. For example, I have seen $\delta(\epsilon)$, so it depends on $\epsilon$ rather than $x$.